# Get the number of section that contains current row

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I my app I got an uitableview with 4 sections. In each section there are some cells that have to differ from cells in another section.
So in this method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I make a variable  `NSInteger row = [indexPath row];`
So that I get the number of a current row (cell). How can I get here the number of section that contains this row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite simple :)

```
NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
```